# Dict inside defaultdict being shared across keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary inside a defaultdict. I noticed that the dictionary is being shared across keys and therefore it takes the values of the last write. How can I isolate those dictionaries?

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> defaults = [('a', 1), ('b', {})]
>>> dd = defaultdict(lambda: dict(defaults))
>>> dd[0]
{'a': 1, 'b': {}}
>>> dd[1]
{'a': 1, 'b': {}}
>>> dd[0]['b']['k'] = 'v'
>>> dd
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f4b3688b398>, {0: {'a': 1, 'b': {'k': 'v'}}, 1:{'a': 1, 'b': {'k': 'v'}}})
>>> dd[1]['b']['k'] = 'v2'
>>> dd
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f4b3688b398>, {0: {'a': 1, 'b': {'k': 'v2'}}, 1: {'a': 1, 'b': {'k': 'v2'}}})
```

Notice that `v` was set to `v2` for both dictionaries. Why is that? and how to change this behavior without much performance overhead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `dict(defaults)` you're not copying the inner dictionary, just making another reference to it. So when you change that dictionary, you're going to see the change everywhere it's referenced.

You need `deepcopy` here to avoid the problem:

```
import copy
from collections import defaultdict
defaults = {'a': 1, 'b': {}}
dd = defaultdict(lambda: copy.deepcopy(defaults))
```

Or you need to not use the same inner mutable objects in successive calls by not repeatedly referencing `defaults`:

```
dd = defaultdict(lambda: {'a': 1, 'b': {}})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your values all contain references to the same object from `defaults`: you rebuild the outer dict, but not the inner one. Just make a function that creates a new, separate object:

```
def builder():
    return {'a': 1, 'b': {}}
dd = defaultdict(builder)
```